# Is having a local database an issue for accessing the website on mobile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, mobile-website, local-database

There's is a "practice" in my new work place. Each and every web application development, the "manager/designer" wants to have a local db.

Currently we are consuming a web service from an external source for getting master data. However he doesn't want to do "through out day" updates into the external source. He wants to keep these updates into the local db and at the end of the day, do a batch update to external source.

Which makes sense for now. But if the website has to be accessed over mobile (in the future - seems like soon...) having a local db-sql processing will be an issue when accessing via mobile?

*Yes the application is layered and have few different interfaces for services, access and connections.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes it gives issues because when you run your application in mobile then it is not going to connect your local db....

It will connect your master db . so updating db at the end of day is not good for mobile users.